# How to run programs with arguments like 'arg=val' (e.g. dd) in rc shell (Linux version ported from Plan9 OS)?

Tags: shell, plan9

I'm trying to use rc shell (Linux port from Plan9 OS) and get 'syntax error' messages when using programs with arguments like **arg=val**.

```
; dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
syntax error
; ls --color=auto
syntax error
```

My guess is that rc shell sees **=** sign and treats the statement as variable assignment, not a program run. May be there's no dd program or other programs using this type of arguments in Plan9. But how can I use it in Linux where they are widely used?

I tried escaping **=** like `dd if\=... of\=`, it didn't help.

I tried quoting arguments like `dd 'if=/dev/zero' 'of=/dev/null' 'bs=1M' 'count=1'` and it worked. But it's not very comfortable. Is there any other more handy way?

I'm using rc shell from Ubuntu 11.10 repository: package version 1.7.1-3ubuntu1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to `man rc`:

> The following characters are special: # ; & | ^ $ = ` ' { } ( ) < >
>   The  single  quote  (')  prevents  special treatment of any character other than itself.

So `=` is a special char which you need to escape.

If you don't like the syntax:

```
ls '--color=auto'
```

you can escape only the `=` char by:

```
ls --color'='auto
```

but I don't think it's any better.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I didn't pay much attention to this part of manual, shame on me. You're right, no other way, only escaping. Also I've found that in Plan 9 OS dd tool uses traditional-style options: -if, -of and -bs instead of if=, of= and bs= and I found that great.